# Can I ask questions about where my code went wrong in algorithms and problem solving?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I have recently started solving problems with Python. Many of the programming problems involve complex algorithms and are hard to solve. I need help knowing if the code I've written produces wrong answers.

For example, I have written code for questions like [this](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1014), and they produce wrong answers. So, can I ask such questions on the site? If not, is there another SE site which solves the above problems?

You see, the question may look like debugging from a point of view and hence StackOverflow doesn't allow it.

Comment: Debugging per-se might not be what Stack Overflow users want to do, but if you pinpoint the problem somewhat, and write a **clear and specific problem**, I believe that your question would be welcome on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### No.

Such code is what we consider broken code. As explained in the [on-topic help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), such code is not welcome here.

> If you are looking for feedback on a specific **working** piece of code from your project in the following areas…

and

> However, if your question is not about a particular piece of code and instead is a generally applicable question about…
>
> - Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
>
> then your question is off-topic for this site.

We don't trouble-shoot. Once you get it working as intended to the best of your knowledge, feel free to post your code. We can help you out improving it once it works.